# Create your font with custom glyph not found symbol

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

I am new to creating/editing fonts. I want to create a font with custom symbol for "glyph not found". I have downloaded FontForge as it seems to be a widespread free font editing program. I was hoping first U+0000 NUL, Default Character would be that, but it seems that I was wrong. I cannot find any info on how to make your own "glyph not found" symbol on google, maybe here somebody could help?

Comment: U+0000 is a defined character and not an un-defined one, so no, that will not work. `.notdef` is a unique glyph on its own and does not have a Unicode assignment. That would defeat its purpose. See http://typedrawers.com/discussion/comment/35074#Comment_35074 (you may want to read the entire thread).

Answer (score 1):

The "glyph not found" glyph (most commonly drawn as a box, often with an X or a question mark inside of it) should be named `.notdef` and it should be glyph 0 in your font. This glyph doesn't normally have a Unicode codepoint.

I believe most font editors will put your `.notdef` glyph into position 0 when generating your font binaries, so long as it's named correctly and does not have a Unicode codepoint.

Source: [Glyph 0: the .notdef glyph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/otspec180/recom#glyph-0--the--notdef-glyph) from Microsoft's *Recommendations for OpenType Fonts*

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!

Answer (score 0):

So far as I'm aware there is no “glyph not found” character. Different programs use different graphic presentations. An empty narrow rectangle is a common rendering, but not the only one. It could also be a rectangle with a question mark in it or with the code number of the character, in hexadecimal, in it.

From the Unicode Spec:

- http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf
- *may be used to represent a missing ideograph*
- → U+20DE $⃞ combining enclosing square

The Unicode [glossary entry says](http://unicode.org/glossary/#replacement_glyph):

> It often is shown as an open or black rectangle.